# How to Block Customers by their Address in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, customer-address, user, zipcode

I want a feature in which user will be blocked by their Address.

Like I will add the address in block list of Magento Admin and then user will not be able to purchase anything if I add their address in back-end(block-list) instead of that it shows an error message on checkout page on clicking on next.

Thanks, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan on blocking the address? If you use the first line of the address they could simply add another letter or a slight typo to bypass it and it would most likely still be delivered.

Comment: Address have different entities separate like city, region, zipcode etc, so specially based on which one you want restrict that user?

Comment: @BenCrook thanks for your response i am planning to block the user by using city , region and zipcode if these 3 are matches then it will show the message.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya thanks for your response i am planning to block the user by using city , region and zipcode like i am creating a back-end drop-down field to choose like block by city , region or zipcode and added the value of it and it will not pass that.
Anything more required please ask.

Comment: And you want compare this with billing address or shipping address?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya No didn't want to compare just for billing address.

Answer (score 0):

Try using observer for `sales_order_place_before` event

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RestrictOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    // If you want to put logic for Billing address then use this one.
    $address = $order->getBillingAddress();

    // If you want to put logic for Shipping address then use this one.
    $address = $order->getShippingAddress();

    //PUT LOGIC OR COMPARISION HERE AND RETURN THE ERROR FROM HERE

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Is this event sales_order_place_before occoured when a order is placed ?
Actually i want when some click on next Shipping Page and the address which is enter by user is block address then show a error on that page user is not going to forward on payment page.
Do you have any idea regarding that how to achieve that ?